# inherit sub-object together with object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I'm using objects `A` and `A.B` with

```
A.myB = A.B;
```

I have an inherited `A1` and `A1.B` where `A1.B` is inherited from `A.B`
and

```
A1.myB = A1.B;
```

The code to achieve this looks like this:

```
A = function() {
    this.myB = this.createB();
};
...
A.prototype.createB = function() {
    return new A.B();
};
```

Then on inheriting A I need to change `.createB`:

```
A1.prototype.createB = function() {
    return new A1.B1();
};
```

I think I'm overlooking something - is there a more straightforward way to set this up, without the need for changing `createB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, while writing this I found an answer. Maybe helpful for anyone out there:

```
A.prototype.createB = function() {
    return new this.constructor.B();
};
```

I think that should do the trick and may be quite handy in combination with the subobject being defined as a property of the main objects constructor.

Comment: only disadvantage seems to be that every inherited A MUST have define its inherited B. I'm accepting my answer but would accept another better answer.